# Sign-in with google doesn't work properly on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin, ios9.3

I am implementing Sign-In with google in my application using cocoa-pods.
I have followed everything in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in.
I have added URL schemes as well.
But when I tried to login with google account in iOS 9, it opens browser and after authentication app doesn't come back to my app and it stuck on browser. But functionality works well on iOS 8. Can anybody help?

OpenURL methods are as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary *)options {
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}
```

Also

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{


    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                      annotation:annotation];


}
```

Comment: If it doesn't comeback then you must be doing soething wrong in the openURL method. Would you please show code related to it ?

Comment: -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
  
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                      annotation:annotation];
  
}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us enough info. But from what you said that it works fine in iOS 8 and not in iOS 9 my guess is getting blocked by AppTransportSecurity (ATS) settings.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: I have tried setting Allow Arbitrary Loads= YES. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9, the SDK should be using `SFSafariViewController` and **not** opening out to the browser.

Are you using the latest version of the SDK? It's 4.0.0 and was released back in May.

**Tip:** If you installed via Cocoapods then ensure that you have run `pod repo update` to ensure you've got the latest copy of the spec repo.